# Study vs. movie problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A boy studying at home for a test decides to take a break for a movie.

Let the distance between the boy's home and the movie theatre be 1 mile.

While walking to the movie he gets half way and changes his mind and return toward his house.

Again, walking toward his house he changes his mind again; heads back toward the movie.

This continues; namely any time he gets half way he reverses direction.

Describe any ending to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the closed interval [0, 1] along the x-axis.

Let x, y, z be points in [0, 1] where the boy’s direction changes.

Let “home” be at point 0.

Let “movie” be at point 1.

Given:

y  =  x + ((1-x)/2)

z  =  y – y/2

We seek a solution such that z = x.

y  =  x + ((1-x)/2)

y  =  1/2 + x/2

z  =  y – y/2

z  =  y/2

z  =  1/4 + x /4

z  = x  implies  x  =  1/4 + x/4

3x/4  =  1/4

x  =  1/3

y  =   2/3

z  =  1/3

Description of an ending to the problem:

The student walks back and forth from a point 1/3 of the distance between home and movie

to a point 2/3 of the distance between home and movie.